# POST with Restsharp doesn't work as expected

Tags: restsharp

I have the following code:

```
var Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var Response = Client.UploadString("myurl", PostData);
```

it works as expected

I am trying to do the same with Restsharp:

```
var Client = new RestClient("myurl");
var Request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
Request.AddBody(PostData);
var Response = client.Execute(request);
```

doesn't work, and:

```
var Client = new RestClient("myurl");
var Request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
Request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", PostData);
var Response = client.Execute(request);
```

doesn't work either...
what am I missing?

Comment: What "does not work" means?

Comment: The server I contact tells me that some data is missing; but it doesn't give any details. The 2 versions of the code look the same to me though

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see the difference between two requests, for example. I think uploading a string and making a REST call (what RestSharp does) are two distinctly different things.

Comment: For some reason I always forget about fiddler... yes, I'm going to try that!